# C# list of generic class with different parameter

Tags: c#

How to store a list of generic class with different parameter

```cs
namespace Cmd;

public abstract class BaseDto
{
}

public abstract class BaseMessage<T>
{
    public readonly T Data;

    public BaseMessage(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public abstract string Embed();
}

public abstract class BaseTopic<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<BaseMessage<T>> Order();
}

public abstract class Dto
{
}

public class Dto1 : Dto
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dto2 : Dto
{
    public string? Address { get; set; }
}

public class Message1 : BaseMessage<Dto1>
{
    public Message1(Dto1 data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public override string Embed()
    {
        return $"{Data.Name}";
    }
}

public class Message2 : BaseMessage<Dto2>
{
    public Message2(Dto2 data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public override string Embed()
    {
        return $"{Data.Address}";
    }
}

public class Topic1 : BaseTopic<Dto1>
{
    public override IEnumerable<BaseMessage<Dto1>> Order()
    {
        var dto = new Dto1();
        var msg = new Message1(dto);
        return new List<BaseMessage<Dto1>> { msg, msg };
    }
}

public class Topic2 : BaseTopic<Dto2>
{
    public override IEnumerable<BaseMessage<Dto2>> Order()
    {
        var dto = new Dto2();
        var msg = new Message2(dto);
        return new List<BaseMessage<Dto2>> { msg, msg };
    }
}
```

is it possible to create a list of topics?
ex :

```cs
var topic1 = new Topic1();
var topic2 = new Topic2();
var list = new List<BaseTopic> {topic1, topic2}
```

what I want is to loop through the list and call message.Embed() after topic.Order got called

I considered using the base DTO class, but it did not work. The error message stated that the argument is not assignable

The BaseTopic class has a generic type parameter because its method requires a generic return value.

Comment: You're not using the return value of `l.Order()` in your example.  so either make it void (if you do not need the return value) or demonstrate how you want to make use of the `IEnumerable<???>` that it is trying to return.  If the only thing you want to do with a `BaseMessage<T>` is `Print` it (which doesn't require the generic parameter `T`, it takes no argument and always returns a `string`), then make a non-generic interface for that method e.g. `IPrintable` or whatever.

Comment: @Wyck i already update my question. BaseMessage need generic T because I need it to store data related variable (DTO) and return it's embedded string. However I can't store topics in a list so I can called its respective method. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Give them a common base class. Just like a `List<string>` is different from a `List<int>`, a generic `BaseTopic<T1>` is different from `BaseTopic<T2>`. But your classes need a common base class to be polymorphic.  Start thinking about how `BaseTopic<T1>` is similar to a `BaseTopic<T2>` and create a non-generic `CommonTopic` class that captures those aspects, and make sure that `BaseTopic<T>` inherits from `CommonTopic`.  You're actually naming your generics like `BaseXXX<T>` but that's a **misnomer**.  You should be naming them like `GenericXXX<T>`. You need `class GenericTopic<T> : BaseTopic`